# MySQL COUNT() or SUM()

Tags: mysql, count

I did a search for cities which works well:

```
$sql = "`status`,`name`,`zip`,`city`, `xxx`, `yyy`";

$geo = "(".$radius." * SQRT(2*(1-cos(RADIANS(breit)) * 
cos(".$rad_b.") * (sin(RADIANS(lang)) * 
sin(".$rad_l.") + cos(RADIANS(lang)) * 
cos(".$rad_l.")) - sin(RADIANS(breit)) * 
sin(".$rad_b."))))";

$select = "SELECT $sql, $geo AS distance FROM TABLE Having 
((distance <= '".$area."') or (distance <= 20 && `city` = '".$city."')) && 
`status` BETWEEN '1' AND '10' 
ORDER BY `city` = '".$city."' DESC, distance, RAND()";

$result = mysqli_query($db,$select);
```

Now I want to count how many xxx fields have the value of 1.
Does anyone have a solution?

Thanks JK

Answer (score 0):

you could use

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM table WHERE value = 1

$select1 = "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM table WHERE xxx = 1 HAVING
((distance <= '".$area."') OR (distance <= 20 && `city` = '".$city."'))
ORDER BY `city` = '".$city."' DESC, distance, RAND()";

$result1 = mysqli_query($db,$select1);
```

in this way you should get your value in the $result1 variable

SELECT $sql, $geo AS distance FROM TABLE Having 
((distance <= '".$area."') or (distance <= 20 && `city` = '".$city."')) && 
`status` BETWEEN '1' AND '10' 
ORDER BY `city` = '".$city."' DESC, distance, RAND()

Comment: How should I install it in my query?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not a solution for my query

Comment: @user3270967 so can you tell us what are you lloking for? Do you want the same exact query you had before but obtain just filter the rows with xxx field equal to 1?

Comment: For example: result 23 records totally, 18 records where xxx = 1

Comment: Sorry. With my query I get a total of 23 records. Now I would like to know how many records have the variable "xxx" has the value "1" (For example, it could be 18, the other 5 have the value "0").

Comment: @user3270967 I updated the query with the ame filters you had. I hope this is what you are looking for

Comment: Thanks, but I get no result.